# 301 Redirect only directory strings to new directory .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a directory

/videos/NAMEHERE/ and want to 301 redirect it to /channel/NAMEHERE/ . However I have permalinks that go to /videos/NAMEHERE/post-name-here/ that i still want to work. I only want to change the /videos/NAMEHERE/ to go to /channel/NAMEHERE/ without messing up the post links.

Thanks.
-D

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far and what exactly is the problem with that!

Answer (score 1):

Use RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/videos/([^/]+)/?$ /channel/$1/
```